# Backup of Datastore/Firestore without gcloud import/export

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, backup, gcloud

Hello Google Cloud Platform users!

I am interested in a solution for a regular (let's say daily) backup of Datastore/Firestore databases. Typical use: for some reason (bad "manual" operation, bug, whatever), a series of entities have been wrongly modified or destroyed, or the database is corrupted; in that case, the database version from the previous day will be restored.

I know this has been discussed in previous posts, but mostly through `gcloud datastore|firestore import|export` through files hosted on Google Cloud Storage. The problem is that for large databases (typically for professional applications with thousands and thousands of entities), this approach can take huge time and resources, even if launched in batch during the night (and it can only get worse when the database increases).

A solution that I have thought about would be to copy to another Datastore/Firestore dataset *at each upsert*, but that seems like overkill, since Datastore/Firestore services already guarantees replica anyway. But most of all: it does not address the issue of unwanted writing or deletion of entities if this second database is 100% synced with the original one...

Are there best practices to backup Datastore/Firestore entities for this use case?

Any (brilliant) idea is welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on this project: https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-firestore-backup

I'm a contributor on it, don't hesitate if you have question or if you want new features.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this library. It seems to nicely automate the backup process.

Comment: It's more than a library, you have a Docker container that you can deploy on Cloud Run and customize it with Environment Variables. Then, create a Cloud Scheduler for triggering the Cloud Run periodically and for performing the backup.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment that function is not available for the datastore/firestore, there is a Feature Request to implement the functionality

https://issuetracker.google.com/133662510

Answer (score 0):

Now datastore supports cli based backup/restoration
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/backups